# Laravel Composer Install always returning an error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I am trying to install Laravel, but each time it returns the same error:

```
  [ErrorException]            
  Array to string conversion  

optimize [--force] [--psr]

Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error

  [RuntimeException]              
  Error Output:                   

    [ErrorException]              
    Array to string conversion

optimize [--force] [--psr]
```

My steps:

- Regardless of using root - `sudo -s` or Laravel Forge's default account `Forge` this error occurs
- I have also `chmod -R 777 app/storage` to prevent any permission errors
- Then using the following `sudo composer install`, `sudo composer update`, the error still persists:

`Writing lock file`
`Generating autoload files`
`Generating optimized class loader`
`Compiling common classes` `[ErrorException] Array to
string conversion optimize [--force] [--psr]`

Why am I getting this error?! Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: You can run `composer install --no-scripts`. It seems that `php artisan optimize` is failing - but I don't know why.

Comment: try: `composer create-project laravel/laravel [FOLDER NAME]`
Make sure you are on the directory you want to install laravel at before running the command above

Comment: Hi @kfirba, thank you for you reply. The directory is created through Laravel Forge. It pulls in the master branch from my BitBucket repository, so all of this 'backend' work trying to fix the problem is rather annoying!